# Over ssl/tls can a query string be logged as the request hops around the net before it gets to its endpoint where it can be logged

Tags: http, https, httprequest, httpwebrequest, httpclient

Over ssl/tls can a query string be logged as the request hops around the net before it gets to its endpoint.
I know the endpoint can log the query string. I also know the endpoint server is trusted so I don't mind any logging there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way points of TCP traffic will see HTTPS data as cipher text that can't be decoded.

Logging at a TCP way point would require a MITM (man-in-the-middle) attack, which would require the user to be tricked into accepting a forged certificate (which is why browsers are becoming more strict about limiting click-through).

There are proxies that do SSL inspection (a.k.a SSL intercept), which are effectively doing just such a MITM--but such proxies generate the forged certificates with a CA certificate (Certificate Authority certificate) that is installed as a trusted CA certificate on the organization's clients (often by way of GPO policies).

So if you are in such an organization, you're requests are almost certainly logged (with more detail than just your query string [a.k.a path]), and you're content is being subjected to either malware protection (usually downstream) and/or DLP (Data Loss Prevention, usually to keep you're organization's sensitive information from being leaked).

Comment: This is for a mobile app that makes api calls to Azure (azure http functions and azure proxy functions). So should be safe from SSL intercept and forged certificates. Yes? As long as the mobile device and azure do not get a virus or malware...

Comment: Consider the case of BYOD or using guest wireless at work.  The thing is, enterprise tools for managing mobile devices provide ways to apply polices to the managed devices.  If your app is built as a standalone HTTP client, then you will likely have control over how proxy settings apply to your app.  But, if you don't allow the correct settings in your app, your client's will almost certainly be blocked either at the firewall, by the proxy, or because your TLS stack isn't accepting the forged certificate.  Code your app as standalone, and prompt your users to accept or decline any risk.

Comment: Good points. I think we are covered on this since the app is being deployed only to corporate employees that have registered with Airwatch. But I do question access over VPN.

Comment: HTTPS within VPN is still HTTPS.  One other thing to keep in mind is that TLS uses an HTTP CONNECT, and for proxy connections, the host name, which may be one of many on a server, is passed in clear text.  Of course, you can't really hide the destination IP address.

Comment: According to Microsoft, Azure proxy functions can be used to hide backend resources like blob storage containers. So the final endpoint should be hidden. If this isn't true then proxy functions lose their appeal and only serve as a waypoint to transform http requests and responses. Are you saying that the resource endpoint can't really be hidden?

Comment: Boundary firewalls and proxies (not to mention routers, switches, etc.) are going to see the IP addresses for the particular TCP socket that traverses them.  Azure could be using a reverse proxy, load balancers, and/or NAT'ing, which means the destination IP address for your requests will not be that of the final destination.

Comment: True. Azure proxy functions do work as a reverse proxy. Thanks for the talk!

Comment: Thank you for considering the security of your app--given we're in this world of apps and IoT that makes not such effort.